# Unique Contrains in Vertica DB

Tags: database, transactions, unique-constraint, vertica

*Disclaimer: My DB knowledge comes mostly from Mysql so I might misunderstand some things in vertica...*

I would like to know if there exist a technique of inserting/updating values in vertica while enforcing unique constrains across multiple sessions. Let's assume I have a table:

```
'id', 'unique_field', 'some_filed'
```

And there is a unique constraint on unique_field. My understanding is that in vertica one first needs to do an insert and then do ANALYZE_CONSTRAINTS to verify if the constraint was violated. In my specific case, I have multiple sessions preforming INSERTS to the same table and they may try to push the same record. The sequence for a single session appears to be:

```
Insert into table (id, unique_field, some_field) values (5, 'abc', 'data');
SELECT ANALYZE_CONSTRAINTS(table);
COMMIT;
```

If I run this sequence in two separate sessions, there is a chance that both queries try to insert the same unique_field and for each of them there will be no constrain violation  detected as they're in separate transactions, which will result in duplicate data.

Is there a better way to prevent this from happening ? Or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vertica does not enforce uniqueness of primary key or unique constraints on load due to the potential overhead associated with the operation.

If `ANALYZE_CONSTRAINTS()` is run before committing, you should be able to capture potential duplicates. There's also overhead with doing `UPDATE`s and those should be avoided.

There are ways to enforce uniqueness on load such as using `MERGE`, or staging the data in a temporary table. Each method has its own limitations. You can read more about enforcing uniqueness of data in my [blog post](http://vertica.tips/2014/04/28/enforcing-uniqueness-of-data-on-load/).

**Update:** As of 7.2, Vertica can automatically enforce primary and unique key constraints. See the [documentation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Constraints/EnforcingPRIMARYandUNIQUEKEYConstraintsAutomatically.htm) for more information.

Comment: Just to clarify, ANALYZE_CONSTRAINS() operates within the scope of the transaction it is run on right ? If another parallel transaction is being executed neither of them will "see" that they're each other about to violate a constraint ?

Comment: @phraktal It should be isolated to the transaction.